# Why is the letter "c" pronounced like /s/ when it comes before “e”, “i”, or “y”, but as /k/ elsewhere?

Tags: history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, phonetics, historical-change

Could you please tell me why from an historical point of view that when the letter *c* comes directly before the letters *e*, *i* or *y* in English that we use the /s/ sound, but in other cases we use the /k/ sound?

For example, *c* represent /s/ in *city, center, century, cycling*, but it represents /k/ in *car, camomile, counter, cabbage*.

Comment: Because that's how it is in French, which is where that spelling practice comes from in English. Historically, the /s/ in French (and thus English, at least in the great number of French loan words) developed from /k/ through several rounds of palatalisation.

Comment: Consider "soccer," for which the English are to blame and "fracing," which was the American spelling, at least until recently. (No fair considering "Celtic.")

Comment: There is a great podcast History of English. I think this is episode four or so.

Comment: https://historyofenglishpodcast.com/2012/07/17/episode-5-centum-satem-and-the-letter-c-2/ - yes, it's a great podcast, highly recommended

Comment: In English, C is redundant but in the Irish language, C is quite necessary as it represents an important sound which is the /c/ sound in Irish as in "ceist" (meaning Question in English).

Answer (score 5):

> **TLDR:** Because Latin mostly first came to English through French, we
> picked up the French habit of pronouncing most Latin-derived words with
> ⟨ce⟩ and ⟨ci⟩ using /s/ or sometimes /ʃ/, but never /k/. We
> also got into the habit of not changing spellings once established.

Below please find the short version; the long version exceeds the space allotted to a given post here.

---

## Who can we blame this silliness on?

I do imagine that all this must be opa**qu**e to someone looking
at this as it exists right now; that is, synchronically. That's because there is no [synchronic explanation, only a
diachronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrony_and_diachrony) one.
It is only when examined under the long meandering path we call history
can one understand not just *city, center, century, cycling* and *car,
camomile, counter, cabbage* but also *opaque* and *pique*, *scholar* and *chronic*, *Celtic*
and *Caedmon*, *species* and *special*, *coelacanth* and *Caesar*, and
all the many more besides.

## Blaming the Romans

The heart of the matter has its origin in how English still uses,
with few alterations, an alphabet devised thousands of years
ago by the Ancient Romans for [Latin back around the seventh century
ʙᴄ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet), some twenty-four
hundred years ago.

In this system, the letter ⟨c⟩ always represented /k/, never
/s/. This letter’s own name *cē* was therefore pronounced /keː/.
Since ⟨c⟩ was always /k/, that means that *Caesar* was pronounced
by its owner exactly how it’s spelled: /ˈkaesar/.  Of course, things
have changed a lot since the 100 ʙᴄ – 44 ʙᴄ when Caesar was alive.

Why didn't they spell his name *Kaesar* then?  Because even though the
Romans did originally have a letter ⟨k⟩ named *ka*, appearing in
a few words like [*kalendae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calends),
they really didn't get much use out of it. Having two letters indicate
the same sound was poor design, and this led to confusion in writing
between *kalendae* and *calendae*.  Soon enough, ⟨k⟩ would come to
be banished for centuries with *calendae* winning out, which is why our
own word deriving from it is *calendar* not **kalendar*.

Under the influence of Christian (Roman) missionaries, scribes, and clerics,
the Celtic languages of the British Isles came to be written using the
Latin alphabet under the convention of using ⟨c⟩ for /k/ always.
Notice how we pronounce *Celtic* /ˈkɛltɪk/.  It's also why the Welsh
word for the Welsh language itself is pronounced [kəmˈraiɡ] and spelled
*Cymraeg*: because ⟨c⟩ is still always /k/ under [Welsh orthographic
conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_orthography).
They don’t have a letter ⟨k⟩ because they didn’t need one.

## Blaming the Irish

The Celtic peoples of Britain were literate in the Latin alphabet, but
the waves of invading Saxons, Angles, and Jutes (and Franks and Frisians)
were not.  They wrote using runes, but by the time the seventh century had
rolled around, the writers of Old English swapped out their old runes for
the Latin alphabet which the now-Irish missionaries in turn brought them.

The English modified the alphabet a bit to compensate for things English
ha but Latin did not, yet it was mostly a mapping of the same sounds to
the same letters as the Romans used. When the English found a new sound,
they invented a new letter, like ⟨þ⟩ for /θ/ or ⟨æ⟩ for /æ/.

Originally when one wrote a Latin letter ⟨c⟩ in English, it always
meant /k/ just as it always used to mean that in Latin itself.
So the [English poet Caedmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A6dmon)'s
name started off with just as much of a /k/ sound as did Caesar's.

So why do we pronounce Caedmon with a /k/ but Caesar with an /s/?
Because Caedmon was English, not Roman.  And all this mess we can blame
on the Romans, or at least on those who came after them, meaning the
French, who also came after us in back in 1066.  And that's why this
all got messed up.

## Blaming the French

Because in another three hundred years or so after Caedmon you get
have the Norman Invasion.  The Normans spoke one of Latin’s daughter
languages, Old French, which was the language of the conquerors not
the commoners.  As such, the conquerors' Latinate vocabulary insinuated
itself into the commoners' Germanic language.  Taking place over a few
centuries, this was the impetus that moved Old English to Middle English:
all the Latin injections.

The thing is, the Latin injected into English was not Caesar's Latin
any longer.  The French had had their way with its pronunciation by
folding, spildling, and mutating it into something Caesar would likely
never have recognized if he had had a chance to hear it spoken.

But the written language he might well have been able to figure out.

That's because even as the spoken language of Classical Latin turned
into Vulgar Latin and thence to Proto-Western-Romance and finally to
the Old French which the Conqueror brought with him to England's green
and pleasant land, scholars long struggled to preserve the old spellings
more in keeping with Caesar's pronunciation than with their own.

Although there were a great many of these, one particular sound change
concerns us here. In early Romance, /k/ followed by a front vowel like /i/
or /e/ was unstable. Think how in today's English /t/ followed by the
the semi-vowel /j/ is unstable: said quickly, *hit you* and *did you*
naturally become affricates not stops. I’m sure you see how these things happen, given that.

Exactly what became of that /k/ which had an /e/ or an /i/ or /j/ after it depends on which particular Romance language we're talking about.  There were
all kinds of transition stages for these changes in pronunciation, including ones intermixed with
other yod-triggered sound changes, but in the present-day state of these
language's respective evolutionary paths, Italian got /t͡ʃ/ there,
Spanish got /θ/ (but /s/ in the south and in America), Galego-Portuguese
got /s/ (but /θ/ lingers in the far north), and French got /s/ and at
times /ʃ/.

## Blaming the Greeks

The ⟨y⟩ situation seen in Latin words like *cycle* and *cylinder*
is in some ways different but in others the same.  Latin didn't even
have a letter ⟨y⟩ until it borrowed it from Greek, so these were
originally Greek words. Those were a /k/ in Latin. Since that ⟨y⟩
represented a rounded front vowel in Greek ([/y/ is just rounded
/i/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel)), the same
thing befell ⟨cy⟩ as ⟨ce⟩ ⟨ci⟩.  How *cycle* came to have a
very different vowel than *cylinder* has a story of its own that I will
here forego for brevity's sake, as it has no bearing on your question.

## Blaming the Scholars

So even though ⟨c⟩ used to mean /k/, the current mess all comes down to how because Latin mostly first came to English through French, we
picked up the French habit of pronouncing most Latin-derived words with
⟨ce⟩ and ⟨ci⟩ using /s/ or sometimes /ʃ/, but never /k/.

We also got into the habit of **not changing spellings once established in writing**.

This cannot be stressed enough, because it explains almost all these questions.  Speaking and writing have followed their own separate journeys down through hundreds, even thousands of years. They are two completely different things.

It would make our writing harder to understand if we lost all etymological connection
to our language’s long, long history. But it might make people be able to read it without having to know that then-lost history.

Answer (score 0):

In Portuguese, sometimes "c" is pronounced like "s". I don't know whether it has anything to with what you are trying to know or not.

Every native speaker of Portuguese will never pronounce "car" as "sar" or pronounce "city" as "kity", even if he/she can barely speak English as a second language.

It's natural.

Comment: I don't know that it’s “natural”, but the reason for Portuguese doing this is exactly the same as why English and French and Spanish etc do so: the evolution of Classical Latin where *c* could only represent /k/ to a situation where front vowels following *c* made that old /k/ turn into an /s/.